# Set custom tab "new" badge

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I built a custom MS Teams Tab. When I add this tab to a channel other users see the "New" badge next to the tab's name:

[image]

is there a way how to show the badge using the teams-js SDK / MS graph API call? I'd like to show it when the content in the tab is updated by another user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when tab content is updated the new badge tag doesn't appear. It will appear only when the new tab is added to the channel. This is by design.